# Saving remote image to assets field in entry

Tags: assets

I'm working on importing entries from EE to Craft. I started with the [craftimport plugin](https://github.com/clearbold/craftimport), and I am expanding it to do a bit more. One of the things I need is to save an image from a remote URL into an entry's assets field.

So far I've only managed to save it to disk, and then I can go into Craft admin and index the assets folder, and re-run the import, which will save the relation between the image and the entry using this:

```
$command = craft()->db->createCommand();
$imgRecord = $command
            ->select('id')
            ->from('assetfiles')
            ->where(array("AND", "filename='" . $images[0]['filename'] . "'", "folderId=2"))
            ->queryRow();

if ($imgRecord['id']) {
    $imgFieldRecord = FieldRecord::model()->findByPk($imgFieldId);
    $imgFieldModel = FieldModel::populateModel($imgFieldRecord);
    craft()->relations->saveRelations($imgFieldModel, $entryModel, array($imgRecord['id']));
}
```

So I'm wondering if it's possible to do this whole thing in one run instead of two? I guess the only thing the indexing does is look for images and store them in the database. But I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that tells me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet to get the image in as an Asset in one go would be to use

```
$response = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath($fileLocation, $fileName, $targetFolderId, AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth);
```

- $fileLocation would be the file's location on the disk
- $fileName is the desired file name
- $targetFolderId is the Assets folder, obviously. Look it up in craft_assetfolders table
- The last argument is how to resolve any naming conflicts.

This will return an AssetOperationResponseModel object.

```
$fileId = $response->getDataItem('fileId');
```

This will get you the file Id. For an in-action example, see AssetsController::actionExpressUpload()

**Note:** This will copy the file to the location. This method is intended for importing a file into an Assets source from a different location, say, a temporary folder. It will probably work alright if the file is already in it's intended place, but I still feel like I need to warn you about this

You can also use this to import images to external sources, by the way.